# d3/html simple div tooltip location

Tags: html, d3.js, tooltip

It's a simple test to understand a way to make a tooltip using div. I'm struggling to locate the tooltip div into where the circle is.

Instead of "d3.select(this).attr("cx")" in the div attribute, I tried 
"d3.mouse(this)" and "event.pageX" but the div stays below svg regardless.

Here is the code snapshot.

```
var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};

var svg = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 960)
            .attr("height", 600);

var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("cx", 200)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .style("opacity", 0.5);

var tooltip = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("div")
            .style("visibility", "hidden");

d3.select(".circle")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)

function mouseover() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", "1");

    tooltip
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        // .style("opacity", 1)
} 

function mousemove() { 

    tooltip.html("is it visible?")
        .style("left", (d3.select(this).attr("cx")) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.select(this).attr("cy")) + "px")

}

function mouseout() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)  
        .style("opacity", 0.5);

    tooltip
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        // .style("opacity", 0);
}
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the necessary CSS to position the `<div>`. Just adding `position: absolute;` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)) will position the tooltip div as desired.

I know this doesn't require so much of explanation but I haven't been on SO since a while so just trying to getting back into the groove. :p

Anyway, if you're positioning the `div` by `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY`, here's how it'll look:

```js
var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};

var svg = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 960)
            .attr("height", 600);

var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("cx", 200)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .style("opacity", 0.5);

var tooltip = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("div").classed('tooltip', true)
            .style("visibility", "hidden");

d3.select(".circle")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)

function mouseover() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", "1");

    tooltip
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        // .style("opacity", 1)
} 

function mousemove() { 

    tooltip.html("is it visible?")
        .style("left", d3.event.pageX+'px')//(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.pageY+'px') //(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) + "px")

}

function mouseout() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)  
        .style("opacity", 0.5);

    tooltip
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        // .style("opacity", 0);
}
```

```css
div#visualisation div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualisation">

</div>
```

If you're positioning it at a particular x,y (as in your snippet), it'll look like the following snippet:

```js
var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};

var svg = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 960)
            .attr("height", 600);

var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


g.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("cx", 200)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .style("opacity", 0.5);

var tooltip = d3.select("#visualisation")
            .append("div").classed('tooltip', true)
            .style("visibility", "hidden");

d3.select(".circle")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)

function mouseover() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", "1");

    tooltip
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        // .style("opacity", 1)
} 

function mousemove() { 

    tooltip.html("is it visible?")
        .style("left", (d3.select(this).attr("cx")) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.select(this).attr("cy")) + "px")

}

function mouseout() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)  
        .style("opacity", 0.5);

    tooltip
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        // .style("opacity", 0);
}
```

```css
div#visualisation div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="visualisation">

</div>
```

**Additions**:

1. Added a class 'tooltip' to this tooltip div.
2. Added `pointer-events: none;` to avoid flickering of the tooltip (take it out and you'll notice the difference)

Hope this helps.